# Current view file in Rails helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, templates, erb, activeview

Is there some way to determine what file currently is being rendered by Rails (2.2) in a helper method. An example result would be "/sessions/new.html.erb" or something similar.

I am trying to write a helper function that does something based on the file name that is being rendered, so I need a reliable way to obtain this information. Is there an official way to get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails 2.2 you can use `@template.template`

Answer (score 1):

I now have this extremely ugly solution. Anybody a better idea?

```
begin
  raise "Nasty hack"
rescue 
  render = $@.detect { |bti| /\/app\/views\/(.+)\:\d+\:in \`_run_erb_/ =~ bti }
  return $1
end
```